# Leave your feedback about the Help Center and your closed or downvoted question here

Tags: discussion, help-center

This question is specifically for users who have asked questions that have been closed, downvoted or put on hold by the Stack Overflow community.

We would like to use your feedback to improve the Help Center, and hopefully help new users ask their questions without getting them put on hold or downvoted.

If you could take a few moments, and **please respond to the following questions** in an answer below:

1. Were you able to find the *"What topics can I ask about here"* article in the Help Center?
2. Did the Help Center assist you in understanding what kinds of questions are on-topic?
3. What improvements can we make to the Help Center to help new users better understand the kinds of questions that are acceptable to ask on Stack Overflow?

Thank you!

---

**Quick Link:**

<sub><sup>`[Click here to submit feedback about your question-asking experience.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129)`</sup></sub>

Comment: Do you have a constructive alternative?  The entire meta site is here to allow people to voice their frustrations, questions, whatever.  I'm trying to make this a bit more specific than that.

Comment: I think, if new users participated in this thread, it's a good idea to get feedback. I just don't know how effective it will be. People see "survey" and run. But I'll be sure to use that quick link soon.

Comment: This is a cool idea, but it's gonna get messy fast if people are using that link.

Comment: "*Thank you!*" — Must... Resist... Urge... to edit...

Comment: @gunr, the word 'survey' does not appear prior to your comment. So if you are truly concerned about people leaving because of the use of that word, getting rid of your comment may be the best way to accomplish that.

Comment: Should this be made a meta.SE question? Too often I am taking the (non-informative) "tour" when trying to find out what a SE site is about, sometimes completely forgetting that there is `/Help Center/On Topic`.

Comment: I see a common thread with the answers so far is to make things easier to read for users.

Comment: What's up with all this answers that are unrelated to what's being asked? This is not about "The State of the Stack"...

Comment: As further evidence that no one reads anything, the only answers are from veteran users of the site. > 1yr for all of them /sigh.

Comment: So if I have some specific suggestions for improving the How to Ask page, can I post it here, or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: @Dukeling: If they're detailed and you want feedback on them, make a separate post.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Personally, I think if you are expecting that users are going to read something you have _already_ lost.

Comment: @canon Pretty sure the markdown was a deliberate attempt to make it possible to copy and paste that link :)

Comment: Such a shame that 99% of the authors of crap questions would never bother answering this even if they knew about it :(

Comment: "***This question is specifically for users who have asked questions that have been closed, downvoted or put on hold by the Stack Overflow community.***" — I think the question should be edited to make this bold.

Comment: I have upvoted a lot of questions and I love it, but I never understand how you feel like when you downvote something. It's better if we post a comment explaining our dislike instead. I am one of the biggest fan of  stackoverflow because of it's good quality answers and questions. But sometimes after doing a lot research if someone is not able to find an answer, he should be allowed to question without the fear of downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, although that is probably because I knew from other communities. I'm active on Ask Ubuntu in particular.
2. Not especially. I'm a student programmer, and very inexperienced in what is what.

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

These seem to be quite unspecific.

What's a specific programming problem? Is it an error and a bit of code? Is it me being confused by the documentation?

What's an algorithm, and how is it different from point 1?

Software tools used. I don't know where the limit of this is. "*Help! Google Chrome is flashing rainbow!*" is off topic here, but I think that a lot of devs will use it.

How do I know it is answerable? The point is, I've not managed to answer it!

Combine the `but if your question generally covers…` and `Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:` into one section. We shouldn't have to be trawling through 3+ different sections (across 2 pages, including the `avoid asking subjective questions` on what not to ask page).

Very few new users wants to follow the rules to the letter and check and decipher these rules.

My suggestion is to simplify all of this - maybe into just 1 section.

> **This is what you can ask:**
>
> - You have been coding, and have an issue with the code or specific software.
>   Make sure you have done research into the problem before asking.
>   Include the code that doesn't work, and what you want it to do.
> - You've found a (small) section of code you don't understand. Again, do some research first.
> - A good rule of thumb is to wait at least 12 (?) hours between encountering a problem and asking here. In that time, research it on your own, and keep a record of what you have done - so we don't suggest the same things.
> - This problem should be unique to coding. If it's very general, it's unlikely to be accepted here. Questions about calculating Pi are probably better on [maths.stackexchange.com](http://maths.stackexchange.com). Questions about your web browser should be asked on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). Operating system questions belong on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com).
>
> **This is what you can't ask:**
>
> - Anything that is likely to start opinionated discussions. These questions don't have one, working answer at the end.
> - This include recommendations for software and learning materials. These are all likely to have different answers from different people, and there will never be one "correct" answer.

Comment: I agree with this, I find that when people are desperate to find a solution to a problem aren't too prone on using time reading things not specific to their problem. Making that page more clear and direct to the point could be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

### Perhaps the help center shouldn't start with Meta.

Having directed new users to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in the past, I clicked through this time and noticed that the very first topic was now....Meta Stack Overflow.

> If you are unable to find the answer you need here, you can also search for or ask a question about Stack Overflow on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)!

followed by a list of recent Meta topics.

New users, when presented with a list of things to click on, usually click on the first thing they see.  Presumably, however, we want them to read the actual help topics and take the tour.

Also, good design would suggest that any fallback procedure (i.e. going to Meta if you can't find the topic you want) should be placed at the end.

The rest of the help center home page is a grid of links grouped by category.  The Meta topics could be put in the grid (at the end) or at the bottom of the page.

Alternatively, the help page could omit the mention of Meta altogether, based on the premise that the Help Center is for new users, and people shouldn't even be going to Meta until they have a little experience with the site. The [ServerFault help center](https://serverfault.com/help) does not mention Meta at all.

Answer (score -9):

I've just read through the rules again, because apparently I'm not allowed to ask for tips on which libraries to use because of potential spam?

Ok, when I joined here, my expectation was

> "This is a programming comunity, helping eachother. No matter what"

Well, apparently there are limitations because annoying spammers and sellers post here too? I think it's fair that we can ask what we want, and if people don't feel like answering, well. Don't... The spammers/sellers should be punished for unwanted annoyance don't limit the community! And ofc. not all questions has a clear answer. But if you need to go here to ask for an answer... I bet you'd rather take any suggestion over your own! ;)

This is just something in the rules that seems weird to me. Thought you should know.

Comment: It's not just about those lowlifes, the additional problems are that it's a list of things, which gets outdated very fast even in the unlikely event it ever gets near copletion, and all the answers are about equally valid and probably have fierce partisans. All in all, the SE engine just isn't geared for such.