# Let's improve the How to Ask page(s)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

First things first, I don't think there should be 2 [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) - that's downright confusing.

[The one users see when asking their first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) also has hopelessly too little information.

And the fact that the most attention on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is given towards writing the title (something that anyone can easily edit) is just wrong.

---

Feel free to propose your own (specific) suggestions **to change the How to Ask page**.

Just to clarify - I'm not disillusioned. I know this probably isn't going to make a big difference, if any, but I think it's at least worth giving it a shot.

---

My main idea is to make **a bunch of really short points with dropdowns** (similar to the dropdowns in [the Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

The page will look something like this: (obviously with a bit of fluff at the top)

> - Do a Google search or two.
> - Try to find the answer yourself.
> - Ask a programming question and stick to the rules.
> - Post a short program, but make sure anyone reading your post can reproduce the issue **themselves**.
> - Describe your problem briefly, but completely.
> - Make it relevant to others.
> - Stick around a while, and check in now and again.
> - Format your question properly.
> - Look for help asking for help.

(I think the fourth one is probably too long, but I couldn't find a way to make it shorter without throwing away a lot of its value)

When you click each item, it will get expanded, with the text provided under each bullet below.

> - ##Do a Google search or two.
>
> ... or a search on Stack Overflow.
>
> Have you [thoroughly searched for an
> answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search) before asking your question?
> Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this
> site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This
> demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it
> saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you
> get a more specific and relevant answer!
>
> - ##Try to find the answer yourself.
>
> Code not working? Try to debug it before asking here.
>
> Looking for some code to do something? Try to write some first.
>
> Regardless of your problem, many may be hesitant to help you if you
> don't show an attempt to solve the problem (whatever it may be)
> yourself. So show us those attempts.
>
> - ##Ask a programming question and stick to the rules.
>
> Stack Overflow is for programming questions. **Just** programming
> questions.
>
> We also have [some very guidelines for what's
> allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [asking for
> opinions or open-ended discussions are not
> allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
>
> If your question is about the site itself, ask on [our
> meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). If you're
> looking for a different topic, it might be covered on [another Stack
> Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites).
>
> Please stick to these guidelines. If you don't, you're going to make
> some users very unhappy and they're probably not going to be very nice
> to you.
>
> - ##Post a short program, but make sure anyone reading your post can reproduce the issue **themselves**.
>
> If you post too much code, you're much less likely to get an answer
> as many users will simply skip your question.
>
> Similarly, if you don't give us a complete program, or one containing
> a typo because you rewrote it here, we won't be able to help.
>
> Write a **new** (short) program from scratch to reproduce the issue,
> and post the entire program in the question itself. For more details,
> read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
> Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
>
> You might also create a live example of the problem that you can link
> to (for example, on http://ideone.com, http://sqlfiddle.com/ or
> http://jsbin.com/), but be sure to include the code in your question
> itself - not everyone can access external sites, and the links may
> break over time.
>
> - ##Describe your problem briefly, but completely.
>
> If we can't understand your question, we won't be able to help you.
> Make sure you give us enough details and context, so we can provide a
> useful and relevant answer.
>
> If you're getting an error message, give us the exact message and the
> relevant line numbers.
>
> If code isn't producing the desired output, be sure to include the
> actual and expected output in the question.
>
> But also be careful not to fill your question with an excessive
> amount of details. If you provide way too many details, most users
> will just skip your question.
>
> - ##Make it relevant to others.
>
> We realize that you may mainly be here to find an answer to your
> question, but if you don't try your best to phrase your question in a
> way that will help others in a similar situation in future, a lot of
> users might not want to help you.
>
> - ##Stick around a while, and check in now and again.
>
> Stack Overflow is fast-moving. It's pretty common to get answers
> within a few minutes, but more importantly, someone may not understand
> something about your post and request clarification. If you're not
> around to respond during the half-an-hour or so after you've posted
> your question, it's likely that most will just give up and move on,
> making it much less likely that you'll get an answer, even if you do
> respond eventually.
>
> Similarly, if you're only going to check in a week after someone's
> asked for clarification, they've probably forgotten about the issue
> already, and are much less likely to care a whole lot compared to if
> you responded on the same day.
>
> - ##Format your question properly.
>
> (Stuff about titles, tags, proof-reading and looking at the preview -
> I got lazy)
>
> - ##Look for help asking for help.
>
> In spite of all your efforts, you may find your questions
> poorly-received. Don't despair! Learning to ask a good question is a
> worthy pursuit, and not one you'll master overnight. Here are some
> additional resources that you may find useful:
>
> (Links as per [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: The third bullet is covered at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: All that improvement work just so that new users skip over and don't read it? Eh.

Comment: Also, how is your proposed page (other than the collapsible headers) materially different from http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: @RobertHarvey (It's the fourth bullet now) I think there's still some value in briefly mentioning it in the How to Ask page (it is in [one of the current How to Ask's](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) (and I meant the unexpanded version was too long, if that part was unclear).

Comment: Well, we probably should just ditch the first How to Ask page.  It is the generic, SE-wide page.  The more specific one is editable by me, though I think it's already in pretty good shape as-is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's not extremely different, there's just a lot of changed phrasing (I tried to phrase most things in some form of "you won't get help if you do that" as opposed to just listing rules, as I think, or hope, that this will motivate people more) and stuff jumbled around to highlight what I think is the important stuff. As mentioned in the post, the main part is the collapsible headers.

Comment: Related: [Leave your feedback about the Help Center and your closed or downvoted question here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258129/456814).

Comment: +1 a tldr linking to the whole page is a good idea because that's how most people work: they only read the first 5/10 lines. I would also try to make it context-free - for example "stick to the rules" is not something that a newbie can understand: *there are so many rules*! So you need to get the essence of it in 10 words (not an easy task). Similarly "Make it relevant to others." can probably be expanded a little e.g. "Make it relevant to others: make your question as generic as possible while still addressing your issue." or something similar.

Comment: Checking the magic links: `[ask]` => [ask], `[help/how-to-ask]` =>  [help/how-to-ask]

Comment: Just my opinion, but this might be more effective if you were blunter. Instead of *many may be hesitant to help you* something like *people will downvote and/or ignore your question*, *make some users very unhappy* -> 'you run the risk of getting flagged*, *a lot of users might not want to help you* -> *a lot of users might want to eat your children* etc. Obviously I'm being satirical, but a wishy-washy 'this might happen' is a lot easier to glaze over than 'you will get downvoted'

Comment: +1 - I think we need to also [update the Orange box](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256676/1324033) on the "ask question" page, to help make it more clear to users to how to get to your proposed changes

Comment: Suggestion to shortening bullet 4 - "Post a short program that users reading your post can use reproduce the issue themselves."

Comment: @JamesMassey I agree, but we should probably stay away from "flagged" and "downvoted" - these are probably unknown, meaningless concepts to new users, and some who know about those things care next to nothing about them - they only care about getting answers.

Comment: Indeed it seems awfully stupid to have 2 different "how to ask" pages. They should be merged.

Comment: "Describe your problem in a lot of detail" will be seen as an invitation to waffle; should it be "Describe your problem precisely" or "Describe your problem completely"?

Comment: @Miff True. I edited that part a bit.

Comment: Lots of comments about this being *"another thing user's won't read"* . The real question is why user's don't read these things and if user's aren't reading it is this the appropriate way to communicate this information?

Comment: I asked a question on the old meta regarding the [dual “How To Ask” help pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215727/dual-how-to-ask-help-pages). One is supposed to be site specific, and the other is supposed to be a general SE page. I too think it is confusing, but the response seemed to be "meh".

Comment: Improve how to ask and then implement this: [Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260039/57475)

Answer (score 13):

It may be a good idea to put a list like the following on the *how to ask* page.

> ## Are you asking a good question? Ask yourself the following:
>
> - Is my question on-topic?
>     The following things are **not** allowed on Stack Overflow:
>
>   - A list of things which aren't allowed here, such as questions that are too localized.
> - Can anyone understand and reproduce my problem after reading **only** my question?
> - Am I asking this because I truly can't solve the problem, or because I'm too lazy to try to fix it myself?
> - Is my post **well-written**, **to the point**, using **proper English** and **formatted** correctly?

The list should be kept concise, because users will otherwise just ask the question without reading all of it.

Comment: *`is my question on-topic?`* - isn't this is why I am here on the help-centre page? but I do truly like this one *Am I asking this because I truly can't solve the problem, or* **because I'm too lazy to try to fix it myself?**

Comment: I'd expand *Am I asking this because I truly can't solve the problem, or because I'm too lazy to try to fix it myself?* and also ask (perhaps as the next bullet point) "Have I described what I've tried so far and why it didn't work?"

Answer (score 4):

*tl;dr;

Please do it, it is always good to improve in such aspects, but don't expect it to change anything.

---

While all this information is quite useful and correct, too many of the new people posting questions will just not read it.

All the information they need is already there, more or less. If it was just a matter of presentation, I doubt we would not that many people that evidently do not follow all of our advices.

This is not meant to discourage anyone from making the information and their presentation better; it will surely make a few people think more about it, and in the end be better stackizens.

But unfortunately the majority of people that are of the kind that don't read it now, will not read it later, no matter how good we structure it. What we have to do is to **scream into their faces** to make them listen. This will increase the chances slightly.

Now what does that mean from a presentation perspective on SO? Well, don't beat me, but, you remember clippy? "It looks like you're writing a letter. Would you like me to...". Ok, torture is mean, but what I am imagining is a bite more "AI" (if you want). Try to detect what the user is doing, and then do some popups. Like

- "This question seems to already have an answer here [link to possible duplicate]. Please explain why this is not a duplicate to that one. Then present a bunch of options, and a free text field that will be added to the question.
- "This question seems to contain mostly code. Please add a bit more description about what your actual question about it is".
- "The last question you asked was closed for . Make sure you dont make the same mistake again and do: [small excerpt from howto][link to full howto]"

This can also apply to answers:

- The Answer contains some "thank you" phrase. Upon submit, educate the user about no "thank you" answers, and have him click two buttons: "Yes, its just a thank you, dont post it actually" or "no, this is not a thank you answer, post it anyways". Same for "I had the same problem" (where we should also mention to rephrase it as e.g. "I solve the problem in the following way"). This might make more people stop and think for a moment.

I think the core problem is that people who want to ask a question are in a state of "Uh, I have to finish this now, have a problem, need to solve it, there is a community where people ask questions, let me ask one too, oh wall of text about blablah howto ask blablah, don't bother me now, I need an answer, it won't be bad if I don't follow all of their rules".

People simply won't read all of this at once. They need to be presented with proper pieces of information that relates to their current actions. Those must be presented in a way that to proceed with their action, they need to actually at least read a little bit of what was presented. This should probably done in a way that the psychologically most appealing button to click on when not reading anything will not post a question/answer.

Comment: With regard to answers, I think it would be better to just have the options be "Yes" and "No", with "Yes" displaying a message explaining that these types of posts aren't appropriate after clicked, and "No" just posting it. We could also extend this to link-only answers (perhaps fairly generously, as they'd still be able to post it if they say it isn't one).

Comment: @Dukeling: We might also want to experiment with some and later look at statistics how successful they were. Like having a 50/50 chance of getting the long or short version, and then looking how much clicked on the "no dont post" version and keep the one with the most "hits".

Comment: The reason I'd rather not have the options contain "post" and "do not post" is because people may be predispositioned to clicking "post", regardless of what the containing text actually says. People also tend to be more predispositioned to clicking "Yes", so if they don't read, their post won't get posted, at least at first.

Comment: @Dukeling: Ah, so this is following the last sentence of my answer. We might also go further and vary the question: "Is this a thank you post"? "yes" => dont post. "Is this a real post and not just saying thank you?" yes => post. Probably keeping some of the variation even after an initial experimentation phase would prove useful.

Answer (score 3):

Great ideas, 3 things I would add to the how to ask page would be

> Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.
>
> Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.
>
> Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service.

etc.

Point it right out, tell them from the start as this may automatically help them realize that however well their question is written and formatted it may still be off-topic.

Comment: ...Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. ...

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, exactly!

Comment: [What Stack Overflow is Not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not)

Comment: @CodyGray [Why "What Stack Overflow is Not" was deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137795) is perhaps a better link (as not many have 10k reputation on MSE), but it's rather different if we just mention a few items in a non-community-editable environment (although perhaps I misinterpreted the purpose of your comment).

Answer (score -7):

I will critique too, but from somewhat different point of view.

Offtopic closure still requires a quorum. That's all. No further explanations needed.

Given

- all the ignorant users who never bother to read the rules and all their idea of the site is "This site is for helping people and I need help!",
- all the ignorant rep-whores whose only idea of answer is to spot a copy-paste typo,

The mission is still impossible.

No matter how would you call your pages or closevote reasons. It won't work.

The better idea of rather **allowing ignorant questions** but just having them in a ghetto - still torpedoed by the people who live in the imaginary world, where every rule is followed by everyone.