# More specific message on question page

Tags: feature-request, questions

On StackOverflow, the form to ask a question shows this message in the right sidebar:

> How to Ask
>
> Is your question about programming?
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

In reviewing a number of questions, many of them lack code or a description of how they attempted to answer their own question.  How about including some text to insist on these specific details?  (I think the above message is a little brief.)

Comment: There's already a link to plenty more information; the people asking crap questions aren't reading what's there, how will adding more stuff for them to not bother reading help?

Comment: Open to suggestions... But, it's gotta be clearly better than what's there now.

Comment: In my opinion, we should take advantage of that massive white space (textarea) and use it to reiterate this section (with a placeholder). You can see an example of that here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202745/178816 or if you want to see just the suggested change here is a screen shot http://i.imgur.com/HKZ4ezg.png

Comment: @jonrsharpe, SO should lead by example and provide the details we are requesting of the people who are posting questions.

Comment: I am voting to close my question because it is a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258251/584846

Answer (score 2):

It already does.  It says:

> Provide details. Share your research.

You say that the message is brief.  That's, *by design*.  it's *supposed* to be brief.  It's not supposed to be a full tutorial on how to ask questions.  However, it contains a link to a page that *is* designed to be a tutorial on how to ask good questions, and that page *does* have those details.  That the brief description of the page is brief is *a good thing*.  The brief description of the page shouldn't be filled with lots of information; if it is, it defeats its purpose.

Comment: I don't have the stats on the most common reasons for closing questions, but in my own experience, it's because the questions don't provide code or show their own work.  If there's a more frequent reason, I'd like to hear it.  In any case, adding a line or two *emphasizing* the requirement should help to cut down on the number of questions being closed.  (Yes, it can be brief.)