# What to do to help (probably new) users avoid non-answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see many many NAAs, probably most of my almost 6000 accepted flags.

What would be the advantages and disadvantages of a Stack Overflow drivers license test?

By that I mean something similar to the question wizard, i.e. something which new users have to get through in order to post an answer (or a question but that is targeted by question wizard).
The common concept is to ask a few questions, each of them with one or two correct but "camouflaged" answers among mutiple wrong ones. Those correct answers intentionally give the wrong reason for doing the right thing and might even be phrased a little off-putting. The wrong answers however are intentionally phrased to read very convincing for new users who have one of the often-observed misunderstandings. Selecting one of them results in an explanation of the misconception and why the chosen action is not appreciated on StackOverflow. Selecting the correct (but ill-reasoned) answers results in "Yes. And you obviously understood that the reason for doing that is not (wrong reason) but instead (reason matching StackOverflow ideas)."

I.e.

> Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for having created a full/unregistered account here.
> We would like to help you with getting comfortable with some of the sometimes unintuitive special ideas and concepts of this community, which are different from other communities you might be used to.
> For that purpose we would like you to decide how you would act in a few situations we are going to describe. Based on your answers, we will point out possible misconceptions you might have and help you avoid awkwardness because of them.
>
> 1. You found a very interesting Q/A pair and want to express your gratitude by writing an appropriately appreciative "Thank you.", do you...?
>    a) Participate in the chat and write a polite "Thank your for your great description of a helpful solution."
>    b) Answer to the most recent, top-most post, the one with the good answer and write "Thank you. That is a good explanation."
>    c) Friendliness is for losers. Do nothing.
>    d) Look for other questions with less well-explained answers and try to write a better one to boost your own vanity.
> 2. You found an interesting question, but in order to answer it, you need some clarification which probably will allow you to provide a really simple, technically sound solution to the described problem. Do you ...?
>    a) First write an answer to the discussion thread which points out the lack of detailed information, which will allow you to later, further down in the forum thread, describe your insightful solution.
>    b) Use the "Ask Question" button, to ask the clarification question you need to make an answer.
>    c) If a question does not contain enough information to receive the really good answer then find a better one, which deserves your effort.
>    d) First get some more reputation with your own questions and answers on other questions, because then you will be able to answer this one.
>    e) Write a conditional answer like "If your problem is caused by .... then the solution is to ... ."
> 3. You find a question which is practically covering your own problem, but there are either no solutions at all, or the solution does not work for you. Do you ... ?
>    a) Get the post thread onto a better elaborated track, by answering with more details on your problem.
>    b) Support the questions author by answering in the affirmative that his problem is indeed an important one and also observed by you?
>    c) Do not help the questions author at all and only bookmark the question or use the "follow" feature, to be notified if a solution to your selfish problem is available.
> 4. StackOverflow inconveniently is configured to only show English questions and answers. Do you ...?
>    a) Reconfigure it with the "automatically translate to Somalian" feature. Reading in that language is after all much easier and you can post much better phrased, easier readable answers in your strongest language.
>    b) Instead of working in a language you are fluent in, you stick with the foreign English and post hardly readable answers, which suffer from your not being fluent in English.
>    c) Ask a technically totally clueless acquaintance to help you with your posts. Four eyes and twenty fingers make better texts than half of that.

Note that the answers are intentionally phrased to lure users to the wrong answers.
The result would be to explain the misconception behind that seemingly attractive answer.
This is to avoid the usual "picking the least stupid sounding answer" and to catch the new user in their actual misconceptions. I hope that the proposed phrasing stay on the light-hearted side. The aim is of course not to make fun of newbies. If I failed on that part, please propose improved phrasings, but the idea stays the same.

Also note that this implies my theory that "Post Your Answer" is often misread by non-native English speakers as "your participation in this chat/forum" and these questions target that, too.

That is the idea, now about the obvious disadvantages:

1. The strong goal of Stack Overflow is suffering, to avoid obstacles in the path of potential new users.
2. well that is all I can think of....

Advantages:

1. Number of NAAs (and/or some other delete-worthy answers) is decreased.
2. Analog to the question wizard.
3. feel free to add some

Comment: I did consider making this an answer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373023/why-new-users-dont-read-the-help-center-and-what-we-can-do-about-it But while writing it it felt like leaving that scope.

Comment: Why? If users ignore the current guidance, warnings, and everything we put in front of them to indicate they should NOT ask a a question (or comment) by submitting an answer.  Why should we attempt to put more noise in front of them?  They will do the absolute minimum in order to ask their question.  **The first example question is noise, none of those answers, are considered to be acceptable.**  I review these type of answers daily, on another profile, for a different community. I see the same users will submit the same low quality answers, (half dozen at a time) until they are answer banned.

Comment: "c) Friendliness is for losers. Do nothing." Seriously? How about "Chitchat detracts from getting the information you want. Upvote the question and answer that best helps you."

Comment: If I were a new user to the site, I would leave when I saw the first question of your survey.  Maybe that's your intended effect, but it's almost certainly not in alignment with Stack Exchange's goals.

Comment: Phrasing aside. This could be a quiz that user can take voluntarily to get better antiquated to the site. Some user do struggle with finding out how the site works and go through way too much reading just to find out these things that could be presented in an easy quiz.

Comment: Related: [Should SO have a prequalification process for membership to weed out the 'noise'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254448/215552)

Comment: *Look for other questions with less well-explained answers and try to write a better one to boost your own vanity.* Why would we want to imply that answering a question that lacks good answers is a bad thing?!

Comment: @SecurityHound I am not sure what you mean by the bold part of your comment. You do not know which is the correct option for question 1? The point is that a) it is not more ignorable noise, they have to pass the questions by giving the right answer. b) Each wrong answer (obvioudly given because of a specific misconception) is answered by an explanation of that misconception, so the specific problem which would cause NAAs is discussed. So that c) the "absolute minimum" is to understand and cleanup the misconception.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, not seriously. My phrasing proposals are not more than proposals. The basic idea is independent from the prhasings. Your proposal however is not well targeted to people who have just created an account and hence are guaranteed to have no privileges for upvoting.

Comment: @RObertHarvey Thanks for your input. I accept that in your eyes I failed my goal to stay on the light-hearted side of phrasings. I do not insist on my phrasings. The idea is to ask questions and offer one correct but "camouflaged" answer (which is phrased a little unattractively) and for each often observed misconception an answer which is misleadingly obvious to those with that misconception. Surely, everything can be phrased more friendly, the correct answer however always least appealing.

Comment: @Scratte I like your idea to NOT force this (though that was my intention). As soon as a new user finds out that asking a good question or giving a correct answer is actually not easy, maybe the first time they attract a moderators attention by being flagged, it could be a recommended method of familiarising with the unusual concepts of StackOverflow.

Comment: @BSMP That is what I think of as "camouflaging" the correct answers. I want them to give the wrong reason for doing the right thing. So as to lower the chances of "brute-forcing" through the multiple choice test. I want actual understanding to be the way to find the right answer, not clicking on the politest sounding "noise".

Comment: @HereticMonkey I (quick-)read what you linked and have to agree that it is very close to my wish. If I had found that I would probably have chosen to make an answer there. Good find. Now that I have some feedback here, I will stand with it. Also I perceive that the answers there are focusing on the education before *asking*, while I rely on the question wizard to cover that (or be the point to improve...) and focus on the NAA problem .... which admittedly includes the kind of NAA which are questions instead of answers. As I said/admitted, yes, there is overlap., I confirm your "Related".

Comment: These comments made me see my own concept clearer. I kind of consistently implemented it in the proposed quiz, but was until now not able to explain. Thanks for helping me. That includes those comments who, in a matter-of-fact way, opposed what I described. Maybe my newly added explanation changes those view, but even if not thanks for sharing them.

Comment: @Scratte If you create an answer from your "opt in" idea, it would in my opinion compete for being accepted. (And not only while being the only one... ;-) ) I will however take some time (days maybe) with accepting anything. I think I would accept that answer which proposed the best way (e.g. by modifying or fine-tuning my idea) to achieve my goal, to help new users with avoiding NAAs. Then it (my Question in combination with all constructive answers) would turn into a pure feature request.

Comment: I think many readers are missing the idea behind these example answers: the wrong answers are worded so that they sound correct, while the right answer is worded so it sounds wrong.  **To pass the test, one has to recognize the correct response while ignoring the inappropriate justification that accompanies it.**  I.e. the test is about knowing *what* to do, not about rationalizing *why* it should be done.