# Better guiding new users who ask a question to the page "guide mode" and the "how to ask"

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users, ask-question-form

I'm new to Stack Overflow this month.

I notice that too many new users don't follow the how to ask guide and post really very bad formatted questions: bad title, non formatted code, unusable pictures, poorly written beyond a low level in English... For some of them it is like they take Stack Overflow for a trash can: they make no effort. Many don't take the time to read similar questions which is well presented and functional.

The actual asking page presents a big title on top of the page with a small blue link under it. Here are some suggestions to improve the process:

- This link "Use guided mode" should be bigger to draw attention.
- Below it there could be another link "how to ask", say half the size of the link to the guide itself the third or the three quarters of the size of the title - this link could be in a different color, like red, even there is a how to ask panel at the right of the page because it does not draw attention.

Also, I tried the guided mode, but I have not be able to switch to the standard mode even after deleting cookies: a link is missing on the first page while I see it is available in the next tab but it may be on the first too. The guided mode may be imposed to users that have never post a question regardless of their reputation, having the link to the normal mode if they want use it.

It would also be useful to have a preview mode available like in [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress).

Comment: IIRC correctly users < 150 rep are put in guided mode by default. Are these changes meant for users that are above that rep level?

Comment: I think that this UI suggestion to have a better UX may be applied to all users regardless of their reputation in the standard mode as well as in the guided mode. I did not know that users < 150 rep are put in guided mode by default and it is great. But my suggestion may apply to this mode too in each page. Links may open url in _blank mode to not break the input process.

Comment: Btw if the question seems really easy and trivial. Please don't answer the duplicate. Make the Search the user should have done and flag the post .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let's improve the How to Ask page(s)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258251/lets-improve-the-how-to-ask-pages)

Comment: I don't talk about to improve the content of the **How to ask** page but the **Ask a question** UX process.

Comment: @RameshRajendran This isn't a duplicate of that. It's asking for improvements do a different part of the site.

Comment: @RameshRajendran You are off topic and you should read [Meta is for... Stack Overflow users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: No!  I  got your point. but my point is why I need to show **How to Ask a Question** in UX process. SO  hopes everyone have some basic knowledge for how to ask a question to someone. That's why SO didn't show that in UX side before asking a question. But if an user asked a question  more than 5 times with wrong way, then background thread will intimate them like ,please read the FAQ and correct yourself otherwise you will be terminated . That's why I am thinking this is enough, No more UX changes(guidance) needed for this. :)

Comment: @RameshRajendran The number of bad questions proves the opposite of what you say. First you said that my feature-request "*Better guiding new user...*" is a duplicate of "*Let's improve the How to Ask page(s)*", that is false. And now you say that SO hopes that **all users know how to create a question**, that is false. My proposal aims to help newbies and moonstrucks users in the asking question process, in raw as wizard mode, and so to lighten the work of moderators and administrators, while not disturbing proficient users, using simple and easy ways to implement primary UX practices.