# Some parts of the rules makes me wonder

Tags: discussion

I've just read through the rules again, because aparently I'm not allowed to ask for tips on which libraries to use becuase of potential spam?

Ok, when I joined here, my expectation was

> "This is a programming comunity, helping eachother. No matter what"

Well, apparently there are limitations because anoying spammers and sellers post here too? I think it's fair that we can ask what we want, and if people don't feel like answering, well. Don't...
The spammers/sellers should be punished for unwanted anoyance don't limit the comunity! And ofc. not all questions has a clear answer. But if you need to go here to ask for an answer... I bet you'd rather take any suggestion over your own! ;)

This is just something in the rules that seems wierd to me. Thought you should know.

Comment: Is there a question here because I don't see one?

Comment: I've been told this is a feedback section?

Comment: Yes it is, but what do you want feedback on? It really isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? [Click here to submit feedback about your question-asking experience.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129)

Comment: No, the reason recommendation questions are not allowed is painful experience with them. The answers get voted by popularity, not merit. They tend to age, badly. And they tend to attract waaaay too many answers. So, yeah. Not allowed.

Comment: @gunr2171 i don't really ask for something HERE. because I thought THIS was what you LINKED. =P

Comment: I don't see how they can in any way turn painful! Which is why it's wierd.

Comment: It falls under the category of "shopping questions" (ie. what should I get). See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) regarding the issue.

Comment: You've described the majority of the site's competition.  Every single question is allowable, or close to it, people answer what they want, with whatever they feel like, and that's that.  SO decided that it didn't want to do that, because it generates a *ton* of crap.  The founders decided to create a place where there is a high standard of quality for all questions and answers, and where content that doesn't meet that bar is either quickly fixed up, or removed.  As a result, SO has pretty well crushed most of its competitors.  You can see why your proposal to revert isn't well received.

Comment: @Ledii If you want to know specifically why they're problematic then take the time to do some research and look through any of the hundreds of previous discussions on the topic.  It has been discussed to death.

Comment: When I joined here, my expectation was that nubile young women would rub my coding fingers with scented balms.  I was sorely mistaken.  And so are you.

Comment: // , I think this is closed because people didn't like it, not that it's off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion stems from your initial impression of the community, but not from what the community's norms/conventions actually are.

The [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) link specifies what is accepted by the community as a good, on-topic question:

> ...[I]f your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Most sites in the Stack Exchange network have a similar policy on what is and isn't on-topic for the site.  Recommendations of products are *not* considered on-topic here (both because it's not practical or answerable, and it's explicitly called out in [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as equally valid), but it *may* be on topic on another site in the network.

You have to cast aside your assumptions of the community and understand the conventions laid out by the community itself.